# How to change the color of particular characters in JLabel?

Tags: java, html, swing, fonts, jlabel

How to change the color of particular characters in JLabel? For instance,

```
JLabel lbl = new JLabel("My Text");
```

I would like that `My` has blue color, while `Text` has red color.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, check [How to Use HTML in Swing Components](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html).

```
JLabel lbl = new JLabel("<html><font color=blue>My</font><font color=red>Text</font></html>");
```

Answer (score 4):

Try with html:

```
String labelText =
  "<html><FONT COLOR=BLUE>My</FONT>" +
  "<FONT COLOR=RED>Text</FONT></html>";
JLabel lbl = new JLabel(labelText);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use HTML in JLabels, so this should work:

```
JLabel lbl = new JLabel("<html><span style='color: blue;'>My</span> <span style='color: red;'>Text</span></html>");
```